# How to map a certain URL in nginx to an external website

Tags: nginx, redirect

I would like to download a file hosted on an external CDN whenever the user hits a particular URL in my website.

For ex. I have a certain file hosted at https://asset.mycdn.com/file.exe;

Now when the user hits the URL https://www.mywebsite.com/download , then it should automatically download the file hosted at https://asset.my-cdn.com/file.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Add following in your nginx settings :

```
location ^/download {
        return 301 https://asset.my-cdn.com/file.exe;
}
```